# Google+ +1 button doesn't count

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus-one

I have a Google+ +1 button and seems to work fine since I can see the +1 in a Google search. The problem is that the count box doesn't keep the number of +1.
Am I doing something wrong? You can see on http://itransformer.es

I've added the next html tag:

```
<div class="g-plusone" style="display: clear" data-width="200" data-href="http://itransformer.es"></div>
```

and the next Javascript snippet code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Well, I've found the issue. I was using `http://itransformer.es` URL, while I had to use `http://www.itransformer.es`. Now the +1's are shown.

Comment: So, you didn't generate it through https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button ... why are you asking this question on SO instead of just generating the button you need and copy/pasting the code it gives you?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - That's what I've done. This is the snippet code I pasted from the link you provide. I don't understand why it is not counting the +1's.